# Select item in unordered list and remove attribute

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery script that adds a rel to all footer links:

```
$('#lp_footer a').attr('rel', 'pop');
```

My footer is an unordered list. I would like to select a certain link from the list and add a new rel attribute.
How is that done?

Sample HTML markup:

```
<div id="footer">
  <div class="inner_wrap">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="home.html" rel="pop">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html" rel="pop">about</a></li>
            <li><a href="contact.html" rel="pop">Contact</a></li>
       </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to target the 2nd item in the list (about) and change the rel attribute.

Comment: Can we see the HTML? Which certain link do you want to target?

Comment: Do you distinguish that "certain link" with a specific class or id? Yes, please show us your relevant HTML code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't say what criteria you wanted to use to select a certain link.  If it's by the link text, you can use something like this:

```
$('#lp_footer a:contains("Home")').attr('rel', 'pop');
```

If you want to select by the href attribute, you can do the following to select all  elements where the href begins with "home" (this would be preferable if you are going to have the displayed text translated):

```
$('#lp_footer a[href^=home]).attr('rel', 'pop');
```

Yet another approach, which others have mentioned, is to add a class attribute to the element and search by that.

Comment: Thanks!   $('#lp_footer a:contains("about")').removeAttr('rel', 'pop'); worked!

Comment: Glad it worked for you, Amy!  Please see my modified answer, and vote for my answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

How do you want to choose that certain link?
Assuming it is detected with a specific class, then you can simply do:

```
$('#lp_footer li.certain-list-item-class a').attr('rel', 'pop');
```

where `certain-list-item-class` is the class of parent list item of that certain link.